# Sending large image through TCPClient c#

Tags: c#, file, tcpclient, transfer

I have the following code to send a picture to a receiving application

```
public static void sendFile(string file, string ip)
    {

        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 44451);
            //Console.WriteLine(ip);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Image x = Image.FromFile(file);
            x.Save(ms, x.RawFormat);

            byte[] bytesToSend = ms.ToArray();

            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            nwStream.Flush();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

and I'm receiving the file on the other end with this

```
            NetworkStream nwStream = clientCopy.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[clientCopy.ReceiveBufferSize];


        //---read incoming stream---
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, clientCopy.ReceiveBufferSize);


MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            //ms.Flush();
            //ms.Close();
            String path;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path = @"C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\test"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\test");
            }

            string format;
            if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(returnImage.RawFormat))
            {
                format = ".jpg";
            }
            else if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(returnImage.RawFormat))
            {
                format = ".png";
            }
            else
            {
                format = ".jpg";
            }

            returnImage.Save(@"C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\test\default_pic" + format, returnImage.RawFormat);
```

If i'm sending a picture that is small (around <20kb) the file is received 100% on the other end but if I send a file around >=100kb, the picture is received but only half of the image is loaded. I'm aware of the approach of reading the stream until  all data is read but I don't know how to implement it right.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only calling `Read` once, which certainly isn't guaranteed to read all the bytes. You could either loop, calling `Read` and copying the relevant number of bytes on each iteration, or you could use `Stream.CopyTo`:

```
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
nwStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
// Rewind so that anything reading the data will read from the start
imageStream.Position = 0;
```

... or you could just read the image straight from the network stream:

```
// No need for another stream...
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(nwStream);
```

(It's *possible* that would fail due to the stream being non-seekable... in which case using `CopyTo` as above would be the simplest option.)

Comment: In one example, i'm sending 100kb of data but only 64kb is being read. Will the 2nd code read everything even if only 64kb is being read by the stream?

Comment: @ReiSchneider: It will all be read - but it may take multiple `Read` calls. You should *always* use the return value of `Read`, and never assume you'll be able to read all the data in one call.

Comment: Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(nwStream); Results in an System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

Comment: @ReiSchneider: That suggests you haven't transmitted the bytes correctly then - or that you'd already read some of the stream. Can you provide a [mcve] showing that?

Comment: Using the same code I posted, I sent this file

http://i64.tinypic.com/o8v61s.png
a 646KB image

and received this
http://i68.tinypic.com/243g8q9.png
A 64KB incomplete image

Comment: @ReiSchneider: The code you posted was broken though. I've explained that.

Comment: Yes I read that, I just can't implement correctly how to loop reading the stream.

Comment: @ReiSchneider: Well you shouldn't need to - `CopyTo` should work fine. Although so should loading the image directly from the stream. At least using `CopyTo` would allow you to check the data that you'd read before trying to interpret it as an image though...

Comment: Could you guide me on how to use the CopyTo or how could I implement it with my code? I'm kinda new to the TCPClient of C#, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The TCP protocol (like any other stream protocol) can't be used to transfer data as is. Most of the time it is impossible to know whether all data is arrived or whether it is received unrelated chunk of data together with the expected one. Therefore it is almost always needed to define underlying protocol, for example by sending a message  header (like in HTTP) or defining a message separator (like line break in Telnet; however, using separators for big size messages are impractical). In most simple case it is enough to define very simple header that contains only the length of the message

Thus, in your case you can send 4 byte image length and then the image. On the server side you will read the 4 bytes size and then in the loop call the `Read` until complete message is recieved.

Please note that you can receive more bytes than expected. It means that the last chunk contains the beginning of the next message.

Comment: In this case there's no need for that, as the client is closing the stream after writing only the image data. The length prefix you're describing is more appropriate for cases where there's more than one message.